# consulta sql server a linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, asp

Hola tengo una consulta de SQL Server y quiero pasarlo a linq

SQL

```
select ep.nom_publicacion as Estatus, 
       count(p.id_est_publicacion) AS Cantidad 
from Publicacion p 
inner join estatus_publicacion as ep on ep.id_est_publicacion = p.id_est_publicacion
where MONTH(p.fecha_inicio_publicacion) = 02 
and YEAR(p.fecha_inicio_publicacion) = 2020
group by ep.nom_publicacion 
having count (ep.nom_publicacion)>1
```

Tengo mi código C#

```
public class estpublic
    {
        public string Estatus { get; set; }
        public int Cantidad { get; set; }
    }
```

Aquí tengo mi código LinQ pero no me funciona, no sé si podrían corregirme o ayudarme con otra solución. Gracias.

```
var estatus = (from p in dcdc.Publicacion
                           join e in dcdc.estatus_publicacion on p.id_est_publicacion equals e.id_est_publicacion
                           where p.fecha_inicio_publicacion.Month == 2 && p.fecha_inicio_publicacion.Year==2020
                           group e by e.nom_publicacion into gr orderby gr.Key
                           select new estpublic()
                           {
                               Estatus = e.nom_publicacion,
                               Cantidad = p.id_est_publicacion
                           }).ToList();
            return estatus;
```

Comment: porque no te funciona? te sale algun error o no te devuelve un resultado?

Comment: las propiedades e.nom_publicacion y p.id_est_publicacion que estan en el select no me las reconoce cuando pongo el group by

Comment: Tu `INNER JOIN` del SQL esta relacionándolo al revés, debe estar así: 
`inner join estatus_publicacion as ep on p.id_est_publicacion = ep.id_est_publicacion`.

Comment: El join esta bien declarado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrias aplicar algo como esto

```
var estatus = (from p in dcdc.Publicacion
                join e in dcdc.estatus_publicacion on p.id_est_publicacion equals e.id_est_publicacion
                    where p.fecha_inicio_publicacion.Month == 2 && p.fecha_inicio_publicacion.Year==2020
                group e by e.nom_publicacion into gr
                    where gr.Count() > 1
                select new estpublic()
                {
                   Estatus = gr.Key,
                   Cantidad = gr.Count()
                }).ToList();
```

Como veras al agrupar tendras en `gr` el resultado de esta operacion, pudiendo

- consultar la `Key` para tomar el valor de la propiedad `nom_publicacion` por la cual agrupar
- consultando la cantidad de items que se agruparon bajo esa key, usando `gr.Count()`

Lo que estoy en duda es si te dejara aplicar el filtro `where` por mes y año ya que esto puede que requiera el uso de un `SqlFunction`

[SqlFunctions.DatePart Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.datepart?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_Objects_SqlClient_SqlFunctions_DatePart_System_String_System_Nullable_System_DateTime__)

No se si las propeidades `Month` y `Year` se traducen a `DATEPART` en una query sql

Pero bueno se puede probar y si falla por este motivo hay que usar la `SqlFunction`

Comment: Si, probe usando el DATEPART tiene la misma funcion si me funciona

Answer (score 0):

Definiendo de esta forma el group tendras acceso.

Te dejo la doc oficial.

> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results

```
var estatus = (from p in dcdc.Publicacion
                           join e in dcdc.estatus_publicacion on p.id_est_publicacion equals e.id_est_publicacion
                           where p.fecha_inicio_publicacion.Month == 2 && p.fecha_inicio_publicacion.Year==2020
                           group e by new {e.nom_publicacion, p.id_est_publicacion } into gr orderby gr.Key
                           select gr;
            return estatus;

            foreach (var item in estatus)
            {
                    item.Key.nom_publicacion;
                    item.Key.id_est_publicacion;

            }
```